# why this document.getElementById().value() does not work in my php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

in my php code,i include -

```html
<select class="ht__select" onchange=" sorting('<?php echo $id ?>')" id="sorting">
  <option value="">Default softing</option>
  <option value="low_price">Sort by price low to high</option>
  <option value="high_price">Sort by price high to low</option>
  <option value="new">Sort by new first</option>
</select>
```

after my php section and after the html body tag i write-

```js
function sorting(cat_id) {

  var sort_info = document.getElementByID('sorting').value();
  alert(sort_info);
  window.location.href = "http://localhost/first/ecom_website/frontend/categories.php?id=" + cat_id + "&sort=" + sort_info;
}
```

but my alert box is not showing.
please help me.

Comment: Typo: not `getElementByID` it is `getElementById`

Comment: It’s not working because there is no `getElementByID` method, and `HTMLElements` have no `value` method. If you want to retrieve the value of your `<select>`, read the documentation for [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Online PHP Script Execution</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select class="ht__select"  onchange="sorting('<?php echo $id ?>')" id="sorting">
             <option value="">Default softing</option>
             <option value="low_price">Sort by price low to high</option>
             <option value="high_price">Sort by price high to low</option>
             <option value="new">Sort by new first</option>
    </select>

<script>
 function sorting(cat_id){
        
 var sort_info=document.getElementById('sorting').value;
           alert(sort_info);
           window.location.href="http://localhost/first/ecom_website/frontend/categories.php?id="+cat_id+"&sort="+sort_info;
        }
 </script>
 
</body>

</html>
```

`value()` method doesn't exist on `getElementById`. You can get the value using the `value` attribute.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why they should *try this*.

Comment: Please consider it as the accepted answer, if you think it fits the title.